# Javascript obfuscators can't handle classes (call stack exceeded)

Tags: javascript, class, obfuscation, callstack

Here's the code which makes problems:

```
class Player {
    hasPos = false;
};
```

That's all the code, it doesn't matter it doesn't do anything for now

I tried 3 methods:

#### https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\analyzers\scope-analyzer\ScopeAnalyzer.ts:71
                throw new Error(error);
                      ^
Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at o.analyze (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\analyzers\scope-analyzer\ScopeAnalyzer.ts:71:23)
    at o.traverseScopeIdentifiers (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\node\ScopeIdentifiersTraverser.ts:26:28)
    at _.transformNode (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\node-transformers\preparing-transformers\VariablePreserveTransformer.ts:54:40)
    at visitorFunction (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\node-transformers\preparing-transformers\VariablePreserveTransformer.ts:45:41)
    at Controller.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\node-transformers\NodeTransformersRunner.ts:108:39)
    at Controller.__execute (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\node_modules\@javascript-obfuscator\estraverse\estraverse.js:336:31)
    at Controller.replace (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\node_modules\@javascript-obfuscator\estraverse\estraverse.js:594:27)
    at Object.replace (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\node_modules\@javascript-obfuscator\estraverse\estraverse.js:675:27)
    at N.transform (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\node-transformers\NodeTransformersRunner.ts:74:24)
    at o.runNodeTransformationStage (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\javascript-obfuscator\src\JavaScriptObfuscator.ts:138:44)
```

#### https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

```
JScriptCodeDom.CodeParseException: require QuoteStart , Line 2, Char 10 ---> System.Exception: require QuoteStart
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseFunctionForQuoteStart(CodeFunctionExpression func)
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseFunctionExpression()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.InternalParseStatementCore()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.InternalParseStatement()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseStatement()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseBlock()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseClassExpression(CodeClassExpression cls, Boolean allowemptyname)
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseClassStatement()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.InternalParseStatementCore()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.InternalParseStatement()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseStatement()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.ParseBlock()
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.Parse(String code, String filename, Int32 lineoffset, Boolean keeplinenum)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at JScriptCodeDom.CodeParser.Parse(String code, String filename, Int32 lineoffset, Boolean keeplinenum)
   at ProtectorV1.Protect(String[] codes)
   at ProtectorV1.Protect(String code)
   at ASP.javascript_obfuscator_aspx.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

#### https://obfuscator.io/

```
Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Turning off self-defending makes no difference

Comment: Try using Babel to convert to old style code before obfuscating.

Comment: https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator/pull/916 This feature is currently unsupported.

Comment: Classes are that high-tech? Mainly, I use `browserify` before trying to obfuscate, but it still doesn't work. Does it have some switch to generate code that obfuscators can handle?

Comment: Not classes, but class-field syntax. Just write the normal `class Player { constructor() { this.hasPos = false; } }` instead.

Comment: Good to know @Bergi

Comment: I used Babel and now the obfuscation works, though my pipeline seems kinda bloated: code -> browserify -> babel -> obfuscate